# Ng-Click not being fired

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have made a code snippet which I use in multiple partial views. In all views it seems to work except one. There is nothing special about this particular partial view, and the code snippet is the same on every view.

However, am I not seeing something?

The real problem:

Ng-click on the form submit is not fired. The form is submitted however.

```
$scope.submitNewNoteForm = function () {
        alert("HI");
    $("#new_noteform").on("submit", function (e) {
        alert("yo");

        var formObj = $("#new_noteform");
        var formURL = formObj.attr("action");
        var formData = new FormData(this);
        $.ajax({
            url: formURL,
            type: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            mimeType: "multipart/form-data",
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR)
            {
                $('#new_noteform')[0].reset();
                $('#new_note').modal('toggle');
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
            {
                alert(textStatus);
            }
        });
        //Prevent Default action. 
        e.preventDefault();
        e.unbind();
    }
    );
};
```

Ng-Click method:

Snippet:

```
<div class="card-body card-padding " ng-controller="NoteListCtrl" id="noteslist"> 
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12 actionBar">
                        <div class="fg-line form-group">
                            <input class="form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-empty" ng-model="notesearch" type="text" placeholder="Zoek in notities">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div >
                    <div class="contactperson" ng-repeat="note in allnotes| filter : notesearch" ng-click="getNoteByID(note.id)" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#view_note">
                        {{note.title}}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" id="view_note" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="view_note">
                    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">{{selnote.title}}</h4>
                            </div>
                            <form role="form" action="index.php" method="POST">
                                <div class="container">
                                    <p ng-bind-html="SkipValidation(selnote.content)"></p>
                                </div>
                                <center>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm m-10" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm hec-save waves-effect m-10" name="save_alert">Save</button> 
                                </center>
                            </form>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" id="new_note" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="new_note" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
                    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Nieuwe notitie</h4>
                            </div>
                            <form role="form" action="adresboek.php" method="POST" id="new_noteform" >

                                <input type="hidden" name="ref_id"  value="{{letter.id}}"/>
                                <input type="hidden" name="level" value="3"/>
                                <div class="container">
                                    <div class="fg-line form-group">
                                        <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Titel"/>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-inline">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="radio-inline"><strong>Urgentie</strong></label>
                                            <label class="radio-inline">
                                                <input name="sampleinlineradio" value="1" type="radio" name="urgency">
                                                !</label>
                                            <label class="radio-inline">
                                                <input  name="sampleinlineradio" value="2" type="radio" name="urgency">
                                                !!</label>
                                            <label class="radio-inline">
                                                <input  name="sampleinlineradio" value="3" type="radio" name="urgency">
                                                !!!</label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <textarea class="form-control html-editor" name="content" style="resize:none;"></textarea>
                                <center>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm m-10" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                                    <input type="hidden" name="save_note" value=""/>
                                    <button type="submit" ng-click="submitNewNoteForm()" class="btn btn-success btn-sm hec-save waves-effect m-10" >Opslaan</button> 
                                </center>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Because you already have a form action

Comment: But this should not be a problem, since they are in distinct area. It could be a problem if he had a form in a form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use ng-submit on your form instead of ng-click on the submit button ([doc here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSubmit)) :

```
<form role="form" action="adresboek.php" method="POST" id="new_noteform" ng-submit="submitNewNoteForm($event)">
```

In your controller, you don't need to listen to submit event, it's handled by angular and your function in ng-submit :

```
$scope.submitNewNoteForm = function (e) {
    // To put at the top level
    e.preventDefault();

    alert("yo");

    var formObj = $("#new_noteform");
    var formURL = formObj.attr("action");
    var formData = new FormData(this);
    $.ajax({
        url: formURL,
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        mimeType: "multipart/form-data",
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR)
        {
            $('#new_noteform')[0].reset();
            $('#new_note').modal('toggle');
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
            alert(textStatus);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: In my submitNewNoteForm I am using AJAX to post the form. However, now it refreshes to the controller's page. Passing $event as parameter to the method doesn't do it.

Comment: Changed that, still getting redirected.

Comment: If you remove the ng-click, and set the ng-submit="$event.preventDefault()", the form is still submitting ? If it does, the problem is elsewhere (controller ? module ? html ?)

Comment: If I change the submit to $event.preventDefault() nothing is being submitted. It have chnaged it back to your code. Right now nothing is being submitted either, the script doesn't reaches inside the AJAX function. Is this due to Formdata(this) ? This is not set?

Comment: And if you put `ng-submit="submitNewNoteForm($event)"` + in your controller `$scope.submitNewNoteForm = function (e) { e.preventDefault(); }` ?

Comment: That works. The form is no longer submitting, but than really.. Not submitting :P. Right now it reaches alert's untill it get's to $.ajax().

Comment: Changing FormData(this) to var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById('new_noteform')); did it! Thanks for your help!